# Invalid regular expression with Lookbehind (Work in Chrome, not in Safari)

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, safari

I use a regular expression to replace prepositions and metrics, it contains a Lookbehind construct that Safari doesn't support, even though it can be replaced without losing functionality

Expression (Javascript):

```
(?<!\S)(in|on|under|and|from)(?!\S)(?:\s)
```

Safari error:

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name

I trying change expression on this(Javascript):

```
(?:\s)(in|on|under|and|from)(?!\S)(?:\s)
```

But this option does not find two prepositions together, but only the first of them *(for example, "and on", "from under")*

Answer (score 1):

You can use only the `(?!\S)` at the end to assert a whitespace boundary, and match either the start of the string or a whitespace char at the beginning of the pattern:

```
(?:\s|^)(in|on|under|and|from)(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7Z9Bvd/1)